# How to set up EF relationships with complex FK free DB

Tags: entity-framework

I'm a EF newbie, and I'm trying to move our organization forward by creating some EF support for an existing DB.

The DB has about 120 tables, and at a very rough guess we'll say that they have 25 columns apiece.  For much of the DB there are no FK relationships enforced, and getting that to change is beyond what I can currently control.

If I bring in 5 tables and use the edmx visual editor, I can create my relationships between the tables without undo difficulty.  On the other hand, visually laying out 120 tables with 25 columns apiece and all the relationships for them would be a nightmare.

Is there a way to manually code these relationships?  (I can look in the edmx file and see what is being done to the supporting code when I add a relationship in the visual tool...but I was hoping to avoid dealing with edmx files, since they seem to be focused on the visual layout tools, which are not really feasible for this largish db.)

I spent a decent amount going through this site (and others) trying to find an answer to this beginner type question...but I could easily be missing it.